# Would dragons rule the 18th century?

Tags: alternate-history, dragons

If there were dragons around in the 18th century, the Napoleonic era, would they terrorize humans as in the days of yore? Or would the invention of cannon, explosives, and other innovations end their reign of terror?

To clarify, the dragons have no particular magical abilities, aside from the following physical abilities:

- They're roughly the size of a T-Rex
- Weigh from 0.5 to 1 ton at their heaviest.
- They can fly, up to a height of 10,000 feet.
- Dragons can breathe fire out to about twenty yards, at a temperature of 2,000°C.
- The dragon's hide is equivalent to 2 mm of mild steel in armour.
- Few dragons remain. There may be 1,000 adult dragons per continent.
- They are smarter than chimps, but not sentient or capable of communication.

With this in mind, would humans live in fear of dragons in the 18th century? Or would dragons live in fear of humanity?

Comment: The size of a T-Rex yet lighter than a cow..?

Comment: 2 mm steel equivalent would make these dragons vulnerable to archers. They are running a risk of being hunted into extinction even before the Napoleonic era.

Comment: So they're not sentient but you want to know if they're capable of ruling?

Comment: Where do the dragons live? Geography is important. For example, there were plenty of tigers during Napoleon's time, but they lived far away, in India. Englishmen, Frenchmen and Germans were absolutely not terrorized by tigers.

Comment: @AlexP "Few dragons remain. There may be 1,000 adult dragons per continent." They probably tend to roost in mountainous regions.

Comment: @Johnny consider the fact that many if not most users on here are not native English speakers, and even if they were - many words in the English language have a plethora of possible meanings but always 1 or 2 very well known and mostly used ones. Such as the world 'rule' being used to define either *having command over others* or *a regulation/principle/norm to abide by*

Comment: @Vincent If you want to, you could make it about 40 to 50 metres. 20 metres is about the effective range of the M1A1 flamethrower. Certainly, a flamethrower is not intended to be long-range artillery. So, if you can't out-range your opponent, what do you do?

Comment: @Johnny 1.34mm is at the lower end of plate armor thickness. Longbows were effective (just barely) against typical armor at a range greater than 20 yards.

Comment: @Alexander Are you basing that off the Mike Loades' documentaries? Weapons that Made Britain or such? Because Mike often uses replicas in his tests. So rather than 1.34mm of hardened steel, you might be looking at 18 gauge mild steel cheap armour made in India. Same for most youtube tests, but they rarely tell you the measurements or quality involved. Admittedly, arrows do have pretty impressive penetration powers in modern tests, just shooting at car doors and such.

Comment: @Johnny there have been different tests, and a lot can be discussed, I just want to reiterate that the thickness that we discuss here is at the lower end for a typical breastplate.

Comment: @Alexander Fair point, it's light armour. I could give the dragon more serious armour, but I thought I'd have it at least somewhat vulnerable to small arms. At its size, slight penetration from arrows and muskets won't hurt it much.

Comment: @Alexander Historical records show that bow arrows were ineffective against complete armours. Those were very rare, however, and arrows were still effective against the great majority of soldiers who were only partially armoured - typically torso and helmet, so an arrow in the arm or leg would take them out. Heavy crossbow bolts, on the other hand, had better chance to pierce them. And of course, Napoleonic guns would have no difficulties piercing those. As per an answer below, so few dragons remain because they were hunted to near-extinction.

Comment: @Johnny please [edit] any needed clarifications into the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Europe eradicated their wolves.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_hunting

> In 9th century France, Charlemagne founded an elite corps of crown
>   funded officials called "Luparii", whose purpose was to control wolf
>   populations in France during the Middle Ages.[12] Luparii were
>   responsible for the initial reduction of wolf populations in France,
>   which would become decimated in later centuries.... Wolves could be
>   killed for monetary rewards equivalent to a month's pay. From 1818 to
>   1829, 1400 wolves were killed each year. This high kill rate coincided
>   with the increased distribution of flintlocks... The last confirmed
>   French wolf kill occurred in 1937.

The Americans were even more efficient about wiping out their wolves.

If governments can sponsor the systematic eradication of a large predator like the wolf, they would even more enthusiastically sponsor the eradication of a huge predator like a dragon.  The dragons you describe are formidable but they eat: they can be poisoned and they can be trapped.

As with wolves, a very few dragons would survive in very remote areas.

---

Humans would live in fear of dragons.  Humans still live in fear of wolves.

The dragons which survived would live in fear of humans, this fear conferring a powerful selective advantage.

Comment: This is spot on.  Without sentience and the ability to reason a defence, they're just another animal.  Humans always figure out how to kill animals.

Comment: This is a fair assessment, but I feel it could go into more detail with the answer. Since I specified dragons are more intelligent than chimps, I figure it's reasonable to have the difficulty that dragons are not easily trapped or poisoned. This would probably select for dragons that are poison resistant, or who are wary of suspicious carrion/bait.

Comment: @Johnny that assumes that humans were not capable of fiendishly clever traps and poisoning methods. There were indeed subtle and devious trapping methods available, and a variety of poisons. Wolves didn't need that level of subtlety and complexity. It does mean that the Dragonii need to be a bit better trained, equipped, and paid than their Luparii counterparts.

Comment: @user535733 I'd say more than "a bit". Any hunter or farmer can trap and hunt wolves. These dragons are on a bigger scale than Jurassic Park.

Comment: The Indians made traps with a bent piece of metal or baleen frozen in fat.  The animal (wolf, bear, wolverine) would eat the ball whole.  When it thawed the thing would spring straight and pierce the inside.  That would work for anything that eats chunks of fat whole and are warm inside.

Comment: @Will ? Wolves chew their food pretty well, generally. They don't really gulp stuff like snakes. So either you're talking about a bunch of thumbtack sized bits of metal, that are unlikely to kill or stop the wolf, or you're talking about a trap that is only effective some of the time. You'd be better putting razor-blades in the food.

Comment: Now, if you tied it to something... Say, sharpen a spike of wood or metal or bone on both ends, tie it to something in the middle, put bait around it.  Sometimes you can get critters (fish, canines, whatever) to swallow it.  Simple fish hook.  When they try to leave, it turns crossways, and the harder they pull, the more it digs in. Won't usually kill them, at least not quickly ... but the sheer pain will detain and weaken them enough to manually kill the wolf and take its skin. Classic Inuit trap. Not sure dragons would fall for either trap, though.

Answer (score 0):

Their reign would end. You mention they have no magical ability and you have specified their what their hide is equivalent to. They would need to have some form of built in magical ability to be able to reinforce their hide and make them tough enough to be able to survive...